# mod_rewrite suggestion

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Right now my url format looks like this:

`http://domain.com/index.php?template=user&id=39`

I'm using [this function](http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/create_short_ids_with_php_like_youtube_or_tinyurl) to create unique short string IDs.

What i want to achieve is: `http://domain.com/u/D/` where `u` is the user page and `D` is the unique short string generated by the function previously mentioned.

This is what I tried:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/(.*)/(.*)/$ index.php?template=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

Comment: Does `RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /index.php?template=$1&id=$2 [NC,L]` work for you?

Comment: `RewriteRule ^/?(.*)/(.*)/?$ index.php?template=$1&id=$2 [L]`

Comment: @bary My answer solve your problem? Ive tested and is working

Comment: I found the solution by myself

`RewriteEngine On`

`RewriteRule ^w/([^/]*)/$ /index.php?template=user&id=$1 [L]`

Comment: I think you find the solution but perhaps for another question:-D

Comment: @Death in your script the template is fixed? In your question you ask about put a user and ID dynamic. Anyway my answer doesn't solve your problem?

Comment: in the rule I wrote, both template and id are dynamic!

Comment: No it inst check again what you wrote where `^w/([^/]*)/$ /index.php?template=user&id=$1 [L]` check that `template=user` it shall be `template=$1` anyway... Have a nice week

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/?$ index.php?template=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA]
```